# Google chrome v119.0.6045.199 on Ubuntu 22.04 takes long to boot

Tags: google-chrome

Google chrome v119.0.6045.199 on Ubuntu 22.04 takes long to start.

I have completely uninstalled chrome and reinstalled it, but I am having the same issue.

Comment: In a command line terminal, `systemd-analyze blame` will provide information.  Read `man systemd-analyze`.

Comment: Do you mean, google chrome takes too long to start? Booting refers to computer startup.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, yes, google app initialization.